# regex few occurrences and need last 2 lines matching

Tags: regex

I'm trying to create a regex to output only last 2 lines matching request.
I have a log file with few lines on it and I want to catch last 2 lines with :

first line : "4bccf" and "Media"

second line : "Live" and "4bccf" and "my"

I created one regex for that :
`((?=.*\b4bccf\b)(?=.*\bMedia\b)|(?=.*\bLive\b)(?=.*\b4bccf\b)(?=.*\bmy\b))`

that works but it prints all lines with ("4bccf" and "Media") + all lines with ("Live" and "4bccf" and "my")

I would like to get only the last line of each.
Is it possible to do that in only one regex ?

If you have idea, I'm very interested
Thanks

Comment: What language/tool are you using? Please, give sample file and expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a complex regex (PCRE flavour) that does the job, but I suggest you to write a script in your favorite scripting language. It will be much more maintainable!

**Note:** I have used the `/x` flag that allows comments and doesn't take care of spaces, it' very usefull for readability ;-) . If your regex flavour doesn't support it, remove all the spaces and linebreaks.

```
^                                   # beginning of line
  (?=.*\b4bccf\b)                   # lookahead, make sure we have 4bccf in the line
  (?=.*\bMedia\b)                   # lookahead, make sure we have Media in the line
  (.+)                              # group 1, the whole line
  $                                 # end of line
  (?=                               # lookahead, make sure we have after:
    (?:                                 # non capture group
      (?!                               # negative lookahead, make we haven't after:
        (?=.*\b4bccf\b)                     # lookahead, make sure we have 4bccf in the line
        (?=.*\bMedia\b)                     # lookahead, make sure we have Media in the line
      )                                 # end lookahead
      [\s\S]                            # any character, including linebreak
    )*                                  # end group, may appear 0 or more times
    \z                                  # end of file
  )                                 # end lookahead
|                                 # OR
^                                   # same description as above for the other words to check
  (?=.*\bLive\b)
  (?=.*\b4bccf\b)
  (?=.*\bmy\b)
  (.+)
  $
  (?=
    (?:
      (?!
        (?=.*\bLive\b)
        (?=.*\b4bccf\b)
        (?=.*\bmy\b)
      )
      [\s\S]
    )*
    \z
  )
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/bpwsjv/1)

Comment: thanks for your work
it was to integrate into a rest api request but maybe I will stay with 2 requests instead of 2